# How do I return a tuple of tuples in python? i.e. ((((1, 8), (4, 5)), ((2, 7), (3, 6))),) It keeps returning None

Tags: python, recursion, tuples

I'm working on a recursive algorithm in Python 3 that produces a list containing a tuple of tuples. When I try to return the list, I get none. Can anyone spot what I'm missing?
Here is what I have:

```
def plan_nba_playoff(num_teams):
    games =list(range(1, num_teams+1))
    return plan_nba_helper(games)

def plan_nba_helper(teams):
    newGames = []
    c = len(teams) - 1
    for i in range(len(teams)//2):
        game = teams[i], teams[c],
        newGames.append(game)
        c -= 1
        if i == c and len(newGames) == 1:
            print(newGames)
            return newGames
        elif i == c:
            plan_nba_helper(newGames) #((((1, 8), (4, 5)), ((2, 7), (3, 6))),)

print(plan_nba_playoff(8)) #((((1, 8), (4, 5)), ((2, 7), (3, 6))),)
```

Comment: You are missing something, perhaps a `return` in the `elif`, and probably a `return` after the entire loop.

Comment: Can you point to the part of the code where you "try to return" something but it doesn’t?

Comment: The way it should work is the helper function is called with a list of numbers 1-8(teams). Then the for loop pairs up the teams in tuples which represents a game. This repeats(elif calls the function again with the new list) until the base case, which is all games are now represented within one final game/tuple. (length of list is 1). This is where i want it to return that list of tuples back to the original playoffs function. But it keeps returning None. If i print newGames just before returning it prints perfectly and then returns None.

Comment: I got it running!  Thanks tevemadar and Zeke Marffy, you were both correct. I just needed to return the recursive call to plan_nba_helper(newGames).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to make your function `plan_nba_helper` return anything. I think you want it to `return newGames` and also maybe the in the `elif` statement you may want to `return plan_nba_helper(newGames)`.

Comment: it also needs a `return` before the recursive call on the last line

Comment: the return is in the if statement.  the elif statement is where the recursive calls happen. once the if statement is true, the helper function should return the current list of tuples.

Comment: @woodall Yes, but what if the `elif` is hit? Then that particular call of the function will return `None`, which will for sure throw off the procedure you are trying to complete. I edited my answer for clarity.

Comment: yep, that was it. Thanks!

Comment: @woodall Sorry that took so long. Make sure to mark an answer as "accepted" if it's the one you want to use. :D That will be my first accepted answer ever… Long live StackOverflow.